# Air temperature chart using ERA5 dataset in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, comparison

I used this code to map 2-meter temperature over Italy from 2000-2020 using ERA5 dataset in GEE.

```
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6dc6f44e827b9e033d2c2227aa2363b1
```

I used Mean reducer to show the mean temperature value over the years, however, if I want to see the temperature change in each year, how can I make its chart? A chart that shows years on the X-axis and mean temperature value of each year on the Y-axis.
Or if I run the script of 2-meter temperature map filtered by date two separate times: first by year 2000-2001 and the other script by 2019-2020, how can I compare these two maps in a numerical way? Since the difference would be very low so the visualization colors do not help to understand the maps. How can I compare the pixel values of two maps to this extent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by creating an image collection where every image represent the yearly mean. Make sure each image has a year property. There are several ways to do this, here I'm using a join:

```
var yearlyMeans = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveAll('images')
  .apply({
    primary: Time, 
    secondary: Time, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'year', rightField: 'year'})
  })
  .map(function (image) {
    return ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(image.get('images')))
      .mean()
      .set('year', image.get('year'))
  })
)
```

To create a chart, you can provide that yearly means image collection to a `ui.Chart.image.series()` chart, specifying they year property as the `xProperty`.

```
var scale = imageCollection.first().geometry().projection().nominalScale()  
var chart = ui.Chart.image
  .series({
    imageCollection: yearlyMeans, 
    region: ROI, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: scale,
    xProperty: 'year'
  })

print(chart)
```

Finally, you can visualize the change between two years by calculating the difference between the yearly images.

```
var temp2000 = yearlyMeans.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', 2000).first()
var temp2019 = yearlyMeans.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', 2019).first()
var change = temp2019.subtract(temp2000).clip(ROI)
Map.addLayer(change, {min: -2, max: 2, palette: 'blue,green,white,yellow,red'}, '2000-2019 change')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/02c332c323e7108eea9b6722d3e4b708